# Writing number with 2 digits after the decimal separator automatically

Tags: vba, excel, onchange

I have a code that works, but I would like to simplify it, if possible.
This codes works when the value of a cell inside a range changes. It checks if the data inserted is a number, and then divides it automatically by one hundred, so I do not have to use the character that separate integers and decimals, and this makes a lot of diference when you have thousands of numbers to insert into sheet.

My code is:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Intersecao = Intersect(Target, Range("ENTRANUMEROS"))

If (Not (Intersecao Is Nothing)) And (Not IsEmpty(Intersecao)) Then

    On Error GoTo Fim

    Dim Entrada As Double: Entrada = Intersecao.Value

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(Entrada) Then
        Entrada = Entrada / 100
        Intersecao.Value = Entrada
    Else
        MsgBox ("Invalid data.")
        Intersecao.Value = ""
        Intersecao.Select
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

Fim:
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) you say it divides by `2` but your code actually divides by `100`. (2) Where exactly is your problem? Where exactly do you need a simplification and why? (3) This might be a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) if there is no problem to solve at all and it is only about code beauty.

Comment: Sorry, i corrected the text. I am looking for a more clever way to do this, I mean, insert from numeric keybord, say, 123456, and gets 1,234.56 automatically into the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Excel option Advanced > **Automatically insert a decimal point** > 2
to generally add a decimal point.

There is no way to have this only for a defined range besides using VBA to switch that option:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Intersecao = Intersect(Target, Range("ENTRANUMEROS"))

    If (Not (Intersecao Is Nothing)) And (Not IsEmpty(Intersecao)) Then
        Application.FixedDecimal = True
        Application.FixedDecimalPlaces = 2
    Else
        Application.FixedDecimal = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this example will not preserve the original state chosen by a user.

*(Sorry for the german screenshot.)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My heart knew that Excel is way more friedly than that code I use!

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In VBA you can use this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Application.FixedDecimal = True
    Application.FixedDecimalPlaces = 2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Vityata! I will check this out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment of author:

> I mean, insert from numeric keybord, say, 123456, and gets 1,234.56
>   automatically into the cell

You can devide by 100:

```
result = Format(Number/100, "#,##0.00")
```

Or, take last 2 digits as as decimals as substring:

```
result = MID(number, 1, LEN(number)-2)&"."& RIGHT(Number, 2)
```